# Generic method override c# an explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) error

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class Base
{
}
public class Rabbit : Base
{
}
public abstract class OO
{
    public abstract ICollection<T> Test<T>() where T : Base;
}
public class LOL : OO
{
    public override ICollection<T> Test<T>()
    {
        return new Collection<Rabbit>();
    }
}
```

This formation of class gives following error.

'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: did u try converting casting it.. ICollection

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? `T` is a generic type, which you will pass at run time so it can be of any type. How come you can expect this type to convert to `Rabbit`? You should return `Collection<T>` instead.

Comment: (ICollection<T>) new Collection<Rabbit>();

Comment: I think this line is issue return new Collection<Rabbit>();Agree with @Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class LOL : OO
    {
        public override ICollection<T> Test<T>()
        {
            return (ICollection<T>) new Collection<Rabbit>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Base
{
}
public class Rabbit : Base
{
}
public abstract class OO
{
    public abstract ICollection<T> Test<T>() where T : Base;
}
public class LOL : OO
{
    public override ICollection<T> Test<T>()
    {
        return new Collection<T>();
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Base
{
}
public class Rabbit : Base
{
}
public abstract class OO
{
    public abstract ICollection<T> Test<T>() where T : Base;
}
public class LOL : OO
{
    public override ICollection<T> Test<T>()
    {
        return new Collection<Rabbit>() as ICollection<T>;
    }
}
```